# Passing the Node Object ($node) to another Drupal Site (Instance)?

Tags: nodes

Can i pass the Node Object `$node` to another Drupal Instance (another Drupal Site) ?

- Lets just forget about Node Conflictions .. and problems etc..
- And lets assume i have a `$node` in a Script
- Then ..
- **Is it POSSIBLE to pass a Drupal Node Object `$node` to another Drupal Instance?** (to continue working on that `$node` at the destination Instance end)
- How can i pass a `$node` to another Drupal Site?

Comment: Not a solution but you should try services module and fetch node from other side. Rather then passing it.

Comment: Sorry, but i am not so clear what do you mean. Can you describe a bit more clear please?

Comment: What i understand from the question is, You want to pass node to other drupal instance. What i suggest is to use services module from where you want to pass the node and call the node using from another drupal instance using REST, XMLRPC.. Module link : http://drupal.org/project/services

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks for sharing this. I will be following that module :)

Comment: If it work i will put it in answer, so post the status. :)